# Angular 2. Async function and binding

Tags: angular

I have problem with binding with async function in Angular 2.

The problem is that VK (global variable) has API with async function, and I tryid to wrapper it in Observable. But when I click the very first time on Button, in view {{model?.count}} still is empty. And only after second click I see number from request. How to fix it?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>My First Angular App</h1>
        <button (click)="onClickMe()">Receive data</button>
        <span>{{model?.count}}</span>
        `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private data: Observable<any>;
    model: any;

    onClickMe() {
        this.data = new Observable(observer => {
            VK.api("friends.get", {user_id: 2888170}, data => observer.next(data.response));
        });

        let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
            model => this.model = model
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That global API probably causes some code to run outside Angulars zone and this is the reason Angular doesn't know it needs to run change detection.

Invoking it explicitly should fix this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    private data: Observable<any>;
    model: any;

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    onClickMe() {
        this.data = new Observable(observer => {
            VK.api("friends.get", {user_id: 2888170}, data => observer.next(data.response));
        });

        let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
            model => {
              this.model = model;
              this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        );

    }
}
```

Other ways to fix this is

- use `this.zone.run(...)` with `constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}`
- initialize the global API inside Angular so that it runs inside Angulars zone (not always possible).